# Add yield generator to python function

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have this problem statement:

For optimal performance, records should be processed in batches.
Create a generator function "batched" that will yield batches of 1000
records at a time and can be used as follows:

```
  for subrange, batch in batched(records, size=1000):
      print("Processing records %d-%d" %(subrange[0], subrange[-1]))
      process(batch)
```

I have tried like this:

```
def myfunc(batched):
    for subrange, batch in batched(records, size=1000):
        print("Processing records %d-%d" %
        (subrange[0], subrange[-1]))
     yield(batched)
```

But I'm not sure, since I'm new into python generators, this simply doesn't show anything on the console, no error, nothing, any ideas?

Comment: have you read anything about generators? For example the first google result https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: Your homework assignment says you are supposed to "Create a generator function "batched" …" not call `batched` like you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are lazy, should consume or bootstrap it in order it to do something.

See example:

```
def g():
    print('hello world')
    yield 3

x = g() # nothing is printed. Magic..
```

Should either do:

```
x = g()
x.send(None) # now will print
```

Or:

```
x = g()
x.next()
```

[edit]

Notice that when doing `.next()` explicitly, eventually you'll get `StopIteration` error, so you should catch it or suppress it

Comment: Thank You very much